# php - Get the last modified dir

Tags: php

A little stuck on this and hoping for some help. I'm trying to get the last modified dir from a path in a string. I know there is a function called "[is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)" and I've done some research but can't seem to get anything to work.

I don't have any code i'm sorry.

```
<?php
 $path = '../../images/'; 
 // echo out the last modified dir from inside the "images" folder
?>
```

**For example:** The path variable above has 5 sub folders inside the "images" dir currently right now. I want to echo out "sub5" - which is the last modified folder.

Comment: If you figured out an answer separately, can you post it as an answer separately (rather than editing it into the question itself)? It's more in keeping with Stack Overflow's format of being a Q&A site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use `scandir()` instead of `is_dir()` function to do it.

Here is an example.

```
function GetFilesAndFolder($Directory) {
    /*Which file want to be escaped, Just add to this array*/
    $EscapedFiles = [
        '.',
        '..'
    ];

    $FilesAndFolders = [];
    /*Scan Files and Directory*/
    $FilesAndDirectoryList = scandir($Directory);
    foreach ($FilesAndDirectoryList as $SingleFile) {
        if (in_array($SingleFile, $EscapedFiles)){
            continue;
        }
        /*Store the Files with Modification Time to an Array*/
        $FilesAndFolders[$SingleFile] = filemtime($Directory . '/' . $SingleFile);
    }
    /*Sort the result as your needs*/
    arsort($FilesAndFolders);
    $FilesAndFolders = array_keys($FilesAndFolders);

    return ($FilesAndFolders) ? $FilesAndFolders : false;
}

$data = GetFilesAndFolder('../../images/');
var_dump($data);
```

> From above example the last modified `Files` or `Folders` will show as Ascending order.

You can also separate your files and folder by checking `is_dir()` function and store the result in 2 different arrays like `$FilesArray=[]` and `$FolderArray=[]`.

Details about [filemtime()](http://php.net/filemtime) [scandir()](http://php.net/scandir) [arsort()](http://php.net/arsort)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can accomplish this:

```
<?php

// Get an array of all files in the current directory.
// Edit to use whatever location you need
$dir = scandir(__DIR__);

$newest_file = null;
$mdate = null;

// Loop over files in directory and if it is a subdirectory and
// its modified time is greater than $mdate, set that as the current
// file.
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    // Skip current directory and parent directory
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    if (is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$file)) {
        if (filemtime(__DIR__.'/'.$file) > $mdate) {
            $newest_file = __DIR__.'/'.$file;
            $mdate = filemtime(__DIR__.'/'.$file);
        }
    }
}
echo $newest_file;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work too just like the other answers. Thanks everyone for the help!

```
<?php

    // get the last created/modified directory

    $path = "images/";

    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_dir = '';    
    $d = dir($path);

    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";

    if(is_dir($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
      $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
      $latest_dir = $entry;
    }

    } //end loop

    echo $latest_dir;

    ?>
```