# checking the update time of folders

Tags: php

The following code looks at two directories and then returns the time since the last update of two directories. I want to extend the code to allow to check more than two directories.

That is,

- take an arbitrary number of directories
- calculate the time of last update for each directory
- return the time since the latest update of all directories

Please advise. Thank you.

```
<?php

/*-----
 CONFIG
------*/
$filestat_path = "/nfs/scarab/.../filestat.txt";
$directory = "/nfs/scarab/...";
$devdirectory = "/nfs/scarab/...";
/*-----*/


$stats_array = array();
$counter = 1;


if(is_file($filestat_path)) {
    $file_array = file($filestat_path);
    foreach($file_array as $line) {
        // tab delimited timestamp, filename, counter
        $line = trim($line);
        if(!empty($line)) {
            $line_array = explode("\t",$line);
            $stats_array[md5($line_array[1])] = $line_array;
        }
    }
}

$files = array(); // create empty array

$dir1 = dir($directory); // get directory handler
$dir2 = dir($devdirectory); // get directory handler

$switch = true; //we change this to false as we want to switch to $dir2

do {
    //if    true         this    if not   this
    $file = $switch ? $dir1->read() : $dir2->read(); //dynamically assigning $dir1 or $dir2 to $file according to value of $switch
    $crdir = $switch ? $directory : $devdirectory;
    if ($file !== false) {
        //
        //Your loop handling
        //
        
        if($file == '..') continue; // this is the parent folder
        if($file == '.') continue; // this is the current folder  // this is the php file
        // if(strpos($file, '.jpg') !== false) continue;
        // if(strpos($file, '.jpeg') !== false) continue;
        // if(strpos($file, '.xml') !== false) continue;
        // if(strpos($file, '.gif') !== false) continue;
        // if(strpos($file, '.png') !== false) continue;
        // if(strpos($file, '.m') !== false) continue;
        // if(strpos($file, '.html') == false) continue; // this is the html file
        // if(strpos($file, '.txt') !== false) continue;
        if($file == '.htaccess') continue; // this is the security file
        if($file == 'filestat.txt') continue; // this is the stats file
        $file = $crdir . '/' . $file;
        if(is_dir($file)) continue; // this is the folder
        if(!file_exists($file)) continue;
        $fileinfo = new SplFileInfo($file); // get file info object
        // put the file info into an array with UNIXTIME key.
        $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = array('name'=>$file,'mtime'=>date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime()),'unixtime'=>$fileinfo->getMTime());
        $key = md5($file);
        
        if(array_key_exists($key, $stats_array)) {
            if($stats_array[$key][0] != date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime())) {
                $stats_array[$key][2]++;
                $stats_array[$key][0] = date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime());
            }
        } else {
            $stats_array[$key] = array(
                date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime()),
                $file,
                1
            );
        }
        $datetime = new \DateTime();
        $datetime->setTimestamp($fileinfo->getMTime());
        $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'] = $datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%H:%I:%S');
        if($datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') != '0')
        {
            $days = ($datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') == '1') ? ' day ' : ' days ';
            $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'] = $datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') . $days . $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'];
        }
        
        //
        //END Your loop handling
        //
    }
    elseif ($switch === true) { //switch to $dir2 if not already
        $switch = false;
    }
    else { //if already switched to $dir2, exit loop
        break;
    }
} while (true);

$dir1->close(); // close the handler
$dir2->close();

ksort($files); // sort array by keys in ascending order
$newest_file = array_pop($files); //extract latest file from array

foreach($stats_array as $stat) {
    $counter += $stat[2];
}

printf(
    "Counter %s. (%s US-EST) Time Since Update: <span class='update_time' mtime='%s'>%s</span>.",
    $counter,
    $newest_file['mtime'],
    $newest_file['unixtime'],
    $newest_file['age']// this is formatted date and time string
);



$put = '';
foreach($stats_array as $line) {
    $put .= implode("\t",$line)."\n";
}
file_put_contents($filestat_path,$put);
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php - Get the last modified dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46901426/php-get-the-last-modified-dir)

Comment: That question solves for two directories. This is an extension to more than two directories.

Comment: I see no limitation to two directories. Answers seem to address all subdirectories at a specified path.

Comment: Do not think it addresses subdirectories.

Comment: They certainly do. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901533/924299) uses `scandir()` to find directories at a specified path. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901545/924299) scans the directory of the current script for subdirectories.

Comment: I assume  one needs to read all files including subdirectories at $file = $switch ? $dir1->read() : $dir2->read(). Bu I am not sure how to write it out.